# How can you defend against Force Telekinesis?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Throughout the Star Wars movies, we see several points where Force telekinesis is used on powerful Force users, for example, Yoda Force pushing Darth Sidious and Count Dooku Force pushing Obi-Wan Kenobi. Is there any way for characters (Force users or otherwise) in the Star Wars universe to defend against this? It seems odd that a powerful Force user wouldn't have any way to defend against one of the most basic Force powers that seemingly any Jedi could learn.

Force telekinesis is defined as any usage of the Force to move someone (or in other cases something), such as causing them to levitate, pushing them, or pulling them. Others have defined Force choke as a form of telekinesis, I'm not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: Force lightning seems to work.

Comment: Use Force pull to hold yourself to whatever you're standing on?

Comment: The simplest way is to not give an opponent space and time to use telekinesis. Telekinesis seems to require some level of concentration that seems very hard to maintain under some conditions. Dooku using telekinesis against Obi-wan made sense because he caught him off guard, but he didn't try to do the same thing to Anakin.

Answer (score 4):

> How can you defend against Force Telekinesis?

With force telekinesis.  You can watch the fight between Anakin and Obi-Wan where they both attempt to push each other with the force.  Due to the fact that they simultaneously performed the action, it could be considered a defensive move for at least one of them.

Below is a clip of the scene:

[Anakin vs Obi-Wan force push](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DDSDPZN8zk)